# eclipse plugins for using SOA

Tags: eclipse, plugins, soa

I want to work on SOA project in eclipse, so what plugins I need to install in eclipse?
What is eclipse soa tool? does it need any other plugins or I can do it just with one plugin?

RDGS

Answer (score 3):

You may have a look at [WSO2 Carbon Studio](http://wso2.org/library/carbon-studio) - wich is an open source product.

It contains vast variety of rich development plugins for developing various components of a complete SOA application.

Comment: Thanks Prabath, but is there any version released by eclipse? I prefer don't rely on third-party products